# Separate items from a list of random numbers in a new list

Tags: python, list

I have a list of 1000 random numbers in the interval [1, 12] and I'm looking for a way to separate them in  other lists such that I get new lists only with 1's, other with only 2's, and so on.

My Python code to generate the list is:

```
A=[]
for x in range(1,1001):
    A.append(random.randint(2, 12))
print A
```

Comment: You can count the each number of intervals and make a new list. But why do you want to implement that?

Comment: What exactly is the *point* of your code? What are you trying to achieve with it? Would a count of the number of appearances of each number suffice? Why put them all in a single list to begin with, if that's not what you need?

Answer (score 1):

Create a dictionary with key for each unique element of your list `A`.  Then create a list for each key.

```
f={}
for i in set(A):
  f[i]=[i]*A.count(i)
```

This way say `A` has 82 elements of 2.  A.count(2) = 82.  You want a list of [2,...,2] the length of which is 82.  You can just write [2]*82 to get such a list.

The iterator does this for the number of each element in `A`.

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby` on your `sorted` list, and dict comprehension to build your result dictionary:

```
from itertools import groupby

result = {i: list(g) for i, g in groupby(sorted(A))}

print result
# {1: [1, 1, 1], 2: [2, 2, 2, 2], 3: [3, 3]...}
```

Or to have a list of lists (@ColonelBeauvel), just use a list comprehension:

```
result = [list(g) for i, g in groupby(sorted(A))]
```

Comment: List comprehension is even neater:  `[list(g) for i,g in groupby(sorted(A))]`

Comment: Did this earlier (not with comprehension though) but I thought the dict approach matches OP's question. Adding it. Thanks.

Comment: If a dictionary is needed, you can do dictionary comprehension in a one liner with your code.

Comment: Roger that. Thanks!